# Quasiconcavity of $-\exp(-axy)$ where a is a constant.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Could someone please explain why the function $-\exp(-axy)$ is a quasi concave function. I am confused because an exponential function is convex and hence, $-\exp $ function should be concave.

Comment: a function $f$ is quasiconcave if and only there exists $x_0$ s.t. $f$ is nondecreasing for $x<x_0$ while $f$ is nonincreasing for $x>x_0$. Now try a look of $-e^{-axy}$ at origin

Comment: What definition of quasiconcavity are you using? Did you try calculating the Hessian?

Comment: @OliverJones  I did. But it's not clearly negative semi definite

Comment: @SaraSethia It's a necessary condition.I don't understand your comment. Are the even-numbered principle minors non-negative and the odd-numbered principle minors non-positive?

Comment: @OliverJones I meant I did compute the Hessian. The odd numbered principal minors are negative but the even numbered principal minor (which here is basically the determinant of a 2x2) inclues the term (2axy-1). It's not possible to determine whether this term is positive or negative and hence, it's not possible to determine whether the even numbered principal minor is non-negative.

Comment: @SaraSethia Were any restrictions on $a$ given? Are there any choices of $a$  that make the necessary condition fail?

Comment: @OliverJones nope. The solution only says that this function is not concave and quasiconcave. I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: @SaraSethia That means that the necessary condition is failing for all choices of $a$. If the domain of the function is ${\Bbb R}^2$, then there has to be an ordered pair $(x,y)$, maybe depending on $a$, that makes the condition fail.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the bordered hessian
$$ \bar{H} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & aye^{-axy} & axe^{-axy} \\ aye^{-axy} & -a^2y^2e^{-axy} & ae^{-axy}(1-axy) \\ axe^{-axy} & ae^{-axy}(1-axy) & -a^2x^2e^{-axy} \end{bmatrix} $$
We only need to check the sign of the determinant, which after some algebra gives
$$|\bar{H}| = 2a^3 xy e^{-3axy} $$

If $|\bar{H}|>0$ for all $(x,y)$ then the function is quasiconcave but not quasiconvex. But if $|\bar{H}|<0$ then the function is quasiconvex but not quasiconcave. If $|\bar{H}|=0$ then we cannot conclude anything.

However, in the determinant we see that the $e^{-3axy}$ term is always positive. The $xy$ term can be negative or positive, but if we restrict ourselves to the positive orthant (this is a usual assumption in economics, for instance) then it is also positive. But the $a^3$ term can be positive or negative. For example, $a=1$ yields a quasiconcave (but not quasiconvex) function in the positive orthant; and $a=-1$ yields a quasiconvex (but not quasiconcave) function in the positive orthant.